# mvc @Url.Content.......images not displaying

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using **mvc** **EF6** to display images from SQL server database,

We have saved the image to the local Folder, and its URL to the Database.

doing fine

image url save like

> C:\Users\Naveed\Desktop\EndToEnd\UserImages\6360831428333175151-posterior-teeth.jpg

then i use below code in my **view** to display the **Images**.

```
@model IEnumerable<iSmileFinal.Models.Imaging>
@if (Model != null)
{
<div class="adsm-sec">
    @foreach (var vad in Model)
    {
        <div id="img">
            <div class="adsm-image-wraper">
                @*@{string imagePath = Url.Content("~/UserImages/");}*@

                @*<img src='@Url.Content("~/UserImages/")' alt="no photo" />*@

                <img src='@Url.Content(vad.ImageUrl)' alt="no photo" class="adsm-image" />

                <img src='@Url.Content(String.Format(vad.ImageUrl))' style="width:200px; height:90px;" />
            </div>
        </div>

       <img>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vad.ImageUrl)

        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vad.ImageType)

        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vad.Comments)
    }
</div>
```

}

but it is not displaying the images.
it displays like (See Image)

[image]

i use Google Chrome and FF.

Comment: you dont need Url.Content if you have the full path. just use `<img src='@vad.ImageUrl' `

Comment: not working.......same problem

Comment: it's a bad idea anyway and security risk.. easiest is to just put the files in your web sites directory or create a virtual directory on your web server that points to your UserImages folder and reference the virtual directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C:\Users\Naveed\Desktop\EndToEnd\UserImages\6360831428333175151-posterior-teeth.jpg

This is not an image **url**

This is a physical path to the file. You should not be storing this in your database when uploading an image. Instead you should be storing the url/unique file identifier relative to your web app.

Something like `yourSite/UserImages/uniqueFileName.jpg` or just `uniqueFileName.jpg"`

Now when you render the page, read this value from your db table and use this relative url as the image `src` property. If you are simply storing the filename, you probably need to append it to the storage file location `"UserImages\"+yourFileNameVariable;` and use that to make it relative

If youe `UserImages` directory is in the web root of your application, you can do this

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/UserImages/yourFileName.png")"/>
```

If you are storing file name in your db table, replace `yourFileName.png` with your c# variable /model property name.

For example, If your model/viewmodel has a property called `ImageName`which has the unique file name(just the file name), you can do like this

```
<img  src="@Url.Content("~")/Uploads/@Model.ImageName"/>
```

`@Url.Content("~")` will return the relative path to the web root

**EDIT** : As per the comment.

To show all items. you can move this image tag inside your loop.

```
@model IEnumerable<iSmileFinal.Models.Imaging>
@if (Model != null)
{
<div class="adsm-sec">
    @foreach (var vad in Model)
    {
        <img src="@Url.Content("~")/Uploads/@vad.ImageName" />
    }
 </div>
}
```

Assuming Imaging class has an `ImageName` property in which you will load the file name stored under `~/Uploads` directory.

Comment: @Shyju......this is what i am getting after using your solution from my other question yesterday. could you please let me know how to resolve it?

Comment: string path = DateTime.Now.Ticks + file.FileName;
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UserImages/"), path);

Comment: See my updated answer (last part). You should be storing the filename/relative name only

Comment: <img src="@Url.Content("~/UserImages/yourFileName.png")"/>................how to display all images?

Comment: Just move it inside your loop. See the updated answer.

Comment: with this <img src="@Url.Content("~")/UserImages/@vad.ImageUrl" />.............there is no display...............the path i am getting is like.....<img src="//UserImages/C:\Users\Naveed\Desktop\EndToEnd\UserImages\636083092740482759Radiation-256.png">

Comment: As i **clearly mentioned in the answer**, you should not be storing the full physical path. Store either a relative url or just the file name!

Comment: sorry sorry.......my mistake.....i got it, Thanks a million, let me try

Comment: now i am getting this <img src="//UserImages/636083624323897201printer-icon.png">.......Image saved.....Url Saved.......but no image display ..............

Comment: Why do you have `//` ? Also to verify it works, you can simply copy the image src value and try to access it in a browser (ofcourse with the site name infront of that)

Comment: ("~")/Upload..............just removed this "/" ........and i am Dancing