# Cannot display images using path created Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying display images on the webpage from the folder placed in my project root directory. The path that I am storing in the database is as follows:

> **D:\Projects\OnlineStore\OnlineStore\OnlineStore\Content\Uploads\Images\Bundles\706976d31e274e7ab36986b9bec2f0f9-Object
>   Image.jpg**

The code that generated this path is as follows:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Images/Bundles"), fileId);
photo.SaveAs(path);
```

Image doesn't show using this path. The path that works is as follows:

> **\Content\Uploads\Images\Bundles\706976d31e274e7ab36986b9bec2f0f9-Object
>   Image.jpg**

How do I resolve this issue? I was thinking about using first path to save image file to folder and save second path in the database. But this doesn't seem the right way of doing this.

Comment: Image is within another assembly (dll)?

Comment: Have you tried var path = `Path.Combine(System.Web.Host.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Images/Bundles"), fileId);`

Comment: Can you post your view code ? , so that others can guide better.

Comment: just store image name inly in database as : `706976d31e274e7ab36986b9bec2f0f9-Object Image.jpg` and display the image using any path you like

Comment: Hi Valkyrie! Image is placed under the root directory, so yes i guess.

Comment: Hi @KunalMukherjee. I have tried your technique but the result is no different than Server.MapPath.

Comment: Hi @stom I am using this <img src="@Url.Content(item.ImageUrl)" alt="" /> to display image. Url works fine when copy and paste in separate browser tab but displaying in img tag makes chrome throw resource error.

Comment: @ImranKhan , You can't because accessing  local disk is security issue check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg) , instead use use `<img src="@Url.Content("~")/Content/Uploads/Images/Bundles/@item.ImageUrl" alt="" />` as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Only store FileName in database Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178012/want-to-save-a-image-to-a-folder-and-saving-the-url-in-database).

```
  string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

 //store fileName in your ImageName column of Image your Image table
 //Note: generate unique filename using `Guid` or `PrimaryKey` to overcome    
 //same file name issue.
```

**2.** Use [@Url.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) to show image in view.

```
<img  src="@Url.Content("~")/Content/Uploads/Images/Bundles/@Model.ImageName"/>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275980/mvc-url-content-images-not-displaying)

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
public ActionResult UserRegister(Register Register)
    {
        try
        {
            DbConnection dbHandle = new DbConnection();
            dbHandle.Connection();

             using (SqlCommand UserRegistercmd = new SqlCommand("USPUserRegistration", dbHandle.con))
                {
                    DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime(Register.dateOfBirth);
                    string Random = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyhhmmss");
                    Register.UserPhoto = "../Images/" + Random + Register.userImg.FileName;
                    Register.userImg.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../Images/") + Random + Register.userImg.FileName);
                    UserRegistercmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    dbHandle.con.Open();
                    UserRegistercmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dbHandle.con.Close();
                    ViewBag.error = "Company Registration Sucess";

                    Mail.SendMail(Register.email,"Your User Name and Password ","User Name :"+Register.username+"Paassword :"+Register.password);
                }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.error = "Error!!";
            ExceptionLog.Log(e, Request.UserHostAddress);
            return RedirectToAction("Error_View", "CompanyRegister");
        }
        finally
        {
            Dispose();
        }
        return RedirectToAction();
    }
```

in cshtml use @Url.Content:

```
  <img src="@Url.Content(@Model.UserPhoto)" alt="There is no Image" style="height:150px;width:150px" onclick="ChangeImg()" />
```